# How to create .dll from Nuget package?

Tags: c#, dll, nuget-package

I have a program written in C# and there is a TwitchLib.dll that provides some stuff about Twitch.tv API I guess and I want to update the .dll since there were some changes in API. How can I get .dll from a nuget package (TwitchLib).

I've tried going to /.nuget/packages/twitchlib/3.0.1/ and there is no TwitchLib.dll while for example in /.nuget/packages/twitchlib.client/3.0.3/ there is. I need .dll that is for whole TwitchLib library, not only specific parts of library.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear to me, but it sounds like you should probably just depend on the NuGet package rather than the specific DLL. You might also want to find the source and see whether the layout has changed over time. (That would be a pretty odd *patch-level* change, admittedly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just build the class library by clicking the right click on solution explorer and you will see the NameOfLibrary.dll file in packages folder of your project directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I forgot to mention that I dont have the source code of C# program I just want to update the .dll.

I installed library on plain c# project template and tried to do what you said but I dont have packages folder in solution explorer.

I have: properties, references, app config, packages config, program.cs. That's it

Comment: packages folder isn't displaying as folder in solution explorer. You can see them as References. If you want to see the .dll file, go through File explorer (e.g Windows Explorer) and you will find packages folder in project directory.